# jQuery, ajax .done fired late?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

did anyone have an idea why the:
success, complete and done
event fired 5-10 seconds later than the "xhr.upload.addEventListener("load")" event?

What is the correct event? 
iam not shure, which time the correct upload-time is?

hope, that somebody can help me :)

greets
paD

```
$('body').on('change', '#fileUploader', function() {
// Post-Daten vorbereiten
//var data = new FormData();
//data.append('file', this.files[0]);

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var data = new FormData();

var files = $("#fileUploader").get(0).files;
for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    data.append(files[i].name, files[i]);
}

// Ajax-Call
$.ajax({
    url: '<?=$this->language->modulLink('Upload/DoUpload');?>',
    data: data,
    type: 'POST',
    cache: false,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function() {
        console.log("JETZT");
    },
    complete: function(){
        console.log( "action finished" );
    },
    xhr: function() {
        var xhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
        xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(evt) {
            if (evt.lengthComputable) {
                var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
                console.log(percentComplete + ' :: ' + evt.loaded + ' :: ' + evt.total);
                //Do something with upload progress here
            }
       }, false);

       xhr.upload.addEventListener("load", function(evt) {
            console.log("rdy");
        }, false);

       return xhr;
    },
}).done(function(d) { console.log(d); });
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you are making AJAX call which is **asynchronous**. Ajax sends the Request from the client side and without waiting for the response starts executing the code statements written(in your case event listener) after the AJAX call code statement. Then once it receives the response from server, based on the response it executes either the success/failure method.

(1.) Ajax call is sent 
**-->** 
(2.) Statements after the AJAX call (i.e eventlistener method) are executed
**-->** 
(3.) Server finally responds to AJAX call
**-->** 
(4.) Success method of AJAX call is executed

I recommend you to go through this tutorials. [AJAX](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.ASP)

Comment: hey grep,

thanks for your quick response.
okay, also i have to use the "addEventListener("load")" method to check if the upload its ready?

bye
paD

Comment: I did not get what you are saying here. But if you want addEventListener("load")" to be executed on success of AJAX call, put it in the success method.

Comment: Yes, now iam a little confused.. Why the "load" Event starts over 5-10 seconds earlier than the success, complete or done Event from jQuery?

Comment: yes, but i am not sure, that i understand you correctly. The "Upload-Server" do nothing on the other side of the ajax response. Means: There is only an <? exit; ?>. The percentage of the "on progress" function rises in the first second up to 50-60%, after that, the times count correctly the upload. i tried over 20 scripts.. almost the same error..

Comment: i can't believe.. my proxy server caches the upload. so the upload to the proxy works very fast, but the upload from the proxy to the server are slow.. to the lag to the ".done" event concluded